# Integration by parts involving distribution functions

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

I am facing a problem integrating the following term by parts:
$\int_{b}^a (x-\mu)^2 dF(x)$

I think the first step should be the following:
$(x-\mu)^2 F(x) \Biggr|_{a}^{b} - 2 \int_{a}^b (x-\mu) F(x)dx$

But then I am completely lost on the next steps.

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: That is the point where you substitute expression for $F(x)$

Comment: @ShubhamJohri, there is no expression for F(x). It is a probability distribution function without a density given.

Comment: I am not sure if you can proceed further in a meaningful way without $F(x)$. Are you required to produce some expression? Maybe then it will be easier for us to lead you to that predefined expression.

Comment: Hi @ShubhamJohri, I totally disregarded the fact that we are given F(a)=0 and F(b)=1. Oops, my bad!